# How to retrieve value of a specific field from a MongoDB collection in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database and I need to retrieve the list of values in a field. I have tried with:

```
     FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(eq("data", data)).projection(and(Projections.include("servizio"), Projections.excludeId()));
        ArrayList<Document> docs = new ArrayList();

        findIterable.into(docs);

        for (Document doc : docs) {
            nomeServizioAltro += doc.toString();
        }
```

but it prints

```
Document{{servizio=Antoniano}}Document{{servizio=Rapp}}Document{{servizio=Ree}}
```

While I want an array with these strings:

```
Antoniano,Rapp,Ree
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, it has worked! :D I forgot the add function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try java 8 stream to output a list of `servizio` values.

```
List<String> res = docs.stream().
       map(doc-> doc.getString("servizio")).
       collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Using for loop

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList();
for(Document doc: docs) {
  res.add(doc.getString("servizio"));
}
```